# Reducing the number of arguments passed to a function in node js

Tags: node.js

I have written a code, that calls several callback functions one after the other, but the thing is there are too many arguments passed to the some functions that are not good for code acceptability.

```
    validate.set(value1 , value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, function(response){
some_other_function(value8, value9, value10, value11, value12, value13, function(response){
 })  
})
```

There are many values that are getting passed in the functions but that is not good for good programming(maximum 5 variables we must pass right)
So, is there any way to get all these arguments in other functions that are called)

Ways I thought : 
1. Constructing array or json body and sending.
2. Creating a separate module and then retrieving them(But this way doesn't goes well as the functions are getting values that are changeable, means I am retrieving the values from the request sent to node js and then sending them in functions)

Comment: I think best solution in this case, is to use a json object, then verify that this object has the required keys every time.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code and start using ES6 feature [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). You might need t

```
function doSomething(value1, value2, ...values){
    console.log(value1); // 1
    console.log(value2); // 2
    console.log(values); // [3,4,5,6]
}
doSomething(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. Basically my code problem is that I am passing more than 5 variables in the functions and that function is in separate module. Like if I take your case doSomething(1,2,3,4,5,6); This is there in other module i.e. in other file.js and I am importing it to the main file to run the functionality.

Comment: You can pass array or if you have `key` `value` then object will be really good option.

Comment: Thanks sir then I will go with that.